# Cylindrical Coordinates $\iiint_B \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx \, dy \, dz$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How to solve this problem ?

Determine the volume of,
$$\iiint_B \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\, dx \, dy \, dz$$
where $B$ is the intersection of hemishpere $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4$, $z \geq 0$, with the cylinder $x^2+y^2\leq 1$

I got this so far :

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_1^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}r\cdot \sqrt{r^2+z^2}\,dz\, dr \, d \theta$$
I just wanna know if it is right, if not, why ?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: You might want to do a different order of integration though, and break it into two pieces. An actual cylinder, plus the little cap at the top.

Comment: Intersection with hemisphere gives $r\in[0,1]$, not $[1,2]$.

Comment: Oops, I didn't catch that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}r\cdot \sqrt{r^2+z^2}dz\ dr \ d \theta$

***Edited :*** $2\pi\int_0^1[r\sqrt{4-r^2}+\frac{r^3}{2} \ln(2+\sqrt{4-r^2})-\frac{r^3}{2}\ln r]dr$

$\therefore \boxed{\frac{\pi}{4}[32-14\sqrt{3}+\ln(2+\sqrt{3})]}$

Comment: Hmm, I plugged that integral into mathematica and it gave me $1/4 \pi (32 - 14 \sqrt{3} + \ln[2 + \sqrt{3}])$ which is close to what you got but not exactly the same.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Ur completely right ! Thanks